# Choosing between www.example.com and example.com

Tags: ssl, web, dns, standards

I'm building a website from scratch.

It seems desirable to me to have the "canonical" url be "http://example.com" rather than the older-style "http://www.example.com". My rationale is that shorter is easier to type, especially on mobile.

However, I see some large sites that do not do this. For instance, if you navigate to "http://zillow.com", you will be redirected to "www.zillow.com".

What is the reason for this?

Does lopping off the www come back to bite you when you go to register an SSL cert? (wildcard vs. single subdomain?)

Is it for compatibility with older browsers/devices/libraries/plugins?

More importantly, is lopping off the www kosher with regards to web standards?

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of opinion. I think there is a right answer. Prove to me that it is one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from [this](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/) website, it makes no difference which way you format your URL. It's simply a matter of preference. Many websites will redirect from *example.com* or *example.com/index.html* to the *www.example.com* version. There isn't a general standard, although many websites will use a shorter URL and redirects for a more user-friendly feel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: However, you should stick with one of them.